# WPF - Change grid backcolor on MouseLeftButtonDown

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, background, grid

I have a `Grid` that I am essentially using as a button which I need to change the backcolor gradient to another gradient while the mouse button is down. When the mouse button is released, change it back to the original color. Additionally, I will need to perform some action as well. I am trying to accomplish this in the code behind but maybe this can be done in the xaml? I am going about it this way as customizing a button to the look and feel that I needed was proving to be more difficult. How can I go about this?

XAML:

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Width="40" Height="40" Margin="22,20,22,5">
    <Border BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" DockPanel.Dock="Top" BorderBrush ="#747474" />
    <Border BorderThickness="1,0,0,0" DockPanel.Dock="Left">
        <Border.BorderBrush>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#747474" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#464648" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Border.BorderBrush>
    </Border>
    <Border BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" DockPanel.Dock="Right">
        <Border.BorderBrush>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#747474" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#464648" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Border.BorderBrush>
    </Border>
    <Border BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" BorderBrush ="#464648" />
    <Grid Width="38" Height="38">
        <Grid.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#585858" Offset="0"/>
                 <GradientStop Color="#464648" Offset="1"/>
             </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Grid.Background>
        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="/common/printer_20.png" Stretch="None" />
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several ways to achieve this.

1. Use a `Style` and Visual States. Problem: It would be dirty executing a command.
2. Add a `Behavior` to the `Grid`. Assign the Mouse Events and change `Background` in code. Additionally you can execute a Command.
3. Use a `Trigger` to change the background. Use MVVM Light to execute a `Command`.

Which way would you prefer?